# Inserting an image using CSS content is working for non-pseudo element, is this behavior correct?

Tags: css

According to various documentation (such as [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content)), the "content" property only applies to pseudo elements - :before and :after.

However, I can place images using the content property on regular elements. Text string doesn't work as expected, and combining images and text also doesn't work, but using image alone is working fine. Plus I am able to control the image size via the element size.

Both Chrome and Firefox behaves the same way, so I can't brush this one off as a bug easily.

Now, this is a behavior that I desire, however is this undocumented behavior? Can I rely on this working in the future?

Comment: it applies to all element if you check the new specification: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#content-property

Comment: in the old/current one it applies to only pseudo element: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content so I guess browsers are implementing the new one (or started to do so)

Comment: Please post your CSS+HTML.

Comment: @Dai we don't always need to have a HTML/CSS code to ask a question

Comment: We don't have to have code to discuss, however, providing example code is still desirable, maybe we or others in future might learn something from your code. Or maybe we would like to see if we can reproduce the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) under **Element Replacement**.

> You can replace the contents of an element with either a `<url>` or an `<image>` value.

Hence why you cannot use text in an elements `content`.

```css
#replaced {
  content: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/12668/MDN.svg");
}
```

```html
<div id="replaced">Mozilla</div>
```

This is only a Draft proposal under CSS Generated Content Module Level 3 and so is not really "production" ready and is not without bugs in some browsers that have currently implemented it.

[image]

Whether this can be relied upon in future is open to question pending the proposal being fully adopted into the spec.

Comment: Ah.. I see that part now. Thanks!