# CSS property with no effect, to be read by js getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, css

### Question / TLDR

How would I name a CSS property so that

- it can be picked up by javascript (e.g. `window.getComputedStyle(element)`, or `jQuery.fn.css()`) as the currently active style on an element, but
- it has no effect on how content is displayed?
- (EDIT: Ideally it should have good cross-browser support and feel natural / not too arbitrary.)

### Background / use case

I am programming a responsive tabs / accordion component.
The component should ship with js and css.
But the break point should be defined in site-specific CSS, that is, a CSS file outside of the package.

**The idea:**

Site-specific CSS contains a rule like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  // I want this CSS to feel natural, semantic, and memorable.
  .supertabs {
    __accordion: 1;  /* This is ignored by the browser, see "Problem" below. */
  }
}
```

In javascript I would pick this up like so:

```
// Use jQuery to make this code look simpler.
var $ = jQuery;
$(window).resize(function () {
  $('.supertabs').each(function () {
    // Won't work, because '__accordion' is not a known CSS property name.
    if (window.getComputedStyle(this).__accordion) {
      // Enable accordion.
      $(this).addClass('supertabs-accordion');
      $(this).removeClass('supertabs-tabs');
    }
    else {
      // Enable tabs.
      $(this).removeClass('supertabs-accordion');
      $(this).addClass('supertabs-tabs');
    }
  });
});
```

Then the package CSS can pick this up and apply the change that distinguish accordion vs tabs behavior.

**Problem**:

The property name "__accordion" is unknown, ignored by the browser, and not accessible with `getComputedStyle()`.

### Alternatives I considered

I could use a known property name, but this might have an undesired effect.

I could use the "variable" syntax (`--accordion`), but technically this also has an effect, it is not picked up by getComputedStyle(), and I am not sure at all what Internet Explorer will do with it (we are supporting IE11, fyi).

I could introduce a hidden element and come up with a made-up convention, e.g. if the hidden element is position:absolute, then show the accordion, otherwise show tabs.
The idea is similar to this article, https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importing-css-breakpoints-into-javascript.

The hidden element would work. But I was looking for something less arbitrary, to make this more suitable for a package to be published.

Comment: I would consider a property that only have effect in a particular context ... for example `grid-gap` is only considered if your element is set `display:grid`. If you are sure you will never use CSS grid then you can use it. There is also other properties related to flexbox

Comment: also for CSS variable you need something like this;  `window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('--example-var')`

Comment: @TemaniAfif The "grid-gap" feels quite arbitrary, and there is a tiny-tiny chance that in some niche case it might actually have an effect. Also the more obscure the property, the higher the chance it won't work in an older browser..

Comment: @TemaniAfif Funny how `['property-name']` works only for known regular properties, `.getPropertyValue()` works for known properties and variables, and unknown non-variables are not accessible with either method.

Comment: the grid-gap was a simple example. The idea was to consider a property that apply only in a particular context. In case you have some control over the context it can probably be an idea

Comment: the pseudo element content is really the ideal way to do this considering IE.

Comment: @karthick the pseudo element can be easily used for other purpose

Comment: To me "content" feels less arbitrary, and could contain string values that actually mean something. E.g. check for `content: 'accordion'` on a hidden child element, so the CSS rule could be `.supertabs > .__state {content: "accordion";}`. The "content" has no effect outside of pseudo elements, and putting this on element directly feels more natural to me. But I wonder if some browsers discard this property on regular elements, because it is only meant for pseudo?

Comment: content can be used for regular element too, rarely by the way

Comment: @TemaniAfif "can be used" as in "won't be discarded" or "will have an effect"?

Comment: will have effect because we can add image using `content` .. I am trying to find the related question ..

Comment: here is a example of using content with an element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953323/8620333

Comment: In your example you wrapped in a media query, does this really need to work? Otherwise you could actually make use of a dumb media-query like `@media var-setter {` and access any rules in it navigating through `document.styleSheets` without it never being applied.

Comment: @Kaiido I would like to grab the value from the element itself, not by analyzing the CSS globally..

Answer (score 1):

***Update***: the support of SVG related property is worse than CSS variables. The below will not work on Firefox.

As I commented you can consider the use of properties that are defined only in a particular context like ones related to Flexbox, CSS grid if you are sure that you will not be using any of them or consider properties related to SVG elements that have no effect on common elements like `x`/`y`/`cx`/`cy`/`rx`/`ry`/`d`, etc

```js
$('.supertabs').each(function() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('cx') +" "+ window.getComputedStyle(this).x)
});
```

```css
.supertabs {
  cx: 1;
  x: 2;
}

.alt {
  cx: 0;
  x: 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
<div class="supertabs alt"></div>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
```

As a side note with CSS variables you need to use `window.getComputedStyle().getPropertyValue('--var')`

```js
$('.supertabs').each(function() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(this).getPropertyValue('--var'))
});
```

```css
.supertabs {
  --var:1;
}

.alt {
  --var:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
<div class="supertabs alt"></div>
<div class="supertabs"></div>
```

Comment: I wonder if variables are found in IE11 with getComputedStyle(). I know the variable won't work as a variable in IE11, but will it be detected?

Comment: @donquixote you can always try. From the CSS perspective they aren't supported but I don't know from the JS perspective and I cannot test ..

Comment: Your solution will work, and I think I am going to accept this eventually. It still feels arbitrary and not semantic or memorable though. Users of the library would have to check the manual each time to remember which property name is being used.

Comment: @donquixote you can always use CSS variables as main solution and have the SVG one as a fallback

Comment: so the user (site-specific CSS) would need to use the SVG if they want to make it work in IE11? Given that it does not pick up the variables - have yet to test it. I will update once I have a chance to test in IE11.

Comment: @donquixote you write both of them, the CSS variable and the SVG one, and both should have the same value always and you write somewhere that the SVG one is for IE support. Then in your JS code you can easily handle this using and `if` condition and use the SVG one in case the CSS variable fail.

Comment: SVG attributes like `cx` and `x` as presentation attributes and hence accessible to CSS is a very recent thing of SVG2, and for instance FF has begun support it only last few versions, not a good idea to use it as a fallback ;-) (+ it doesn't actually works there, since it shouldn't have any effect on this HTMLelement, they always return the default value '0px'.

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing myself.

The goal was to have consistent behavior across browsers, and to have something that does not feel too arbitrary.

https://jsfiddle.net/dxsmub5g/
Detailed output below.

### Solution I chose

The best solution seems to be `element::before {content: '...';}`, to be read with `window.getComputedStyle(ELEMENT, '::before').getPropertyValue('content');

The `::before` can get a `display: none;` to make sure the content has no effect.

Or even better, put this on a nested div which itself is `display: none;`.

This is also what was suggested in https://www.lullabot.com/articles/importing-css-breakpoints-into-javascript, except they do it directly on the body element.

Something to keep in mind: The value will be a string value in double quotes. Even if you use single quotes in the original CSS, the value will be in double quotes. In most cases `JSON.parse(value)` should remove the quotes, but I am not sure if this is 100% universal, e.g. if you want to encode complex objects within the content property.

### Options that I discarded

- `content:` on a non-pseudo element

  - IE11 does not detect string value.
- `--varname:` (css variable):

  - not detected by IE11.
- unknown properties

  - generally not working in any browser.
- svg properties ('cx'):

  - might not work on some older browsers
  - IE11 needs `['cx']` syntax instead of `.getPropertyValue('cx')`
  - not semantic, feels arbitrary.
  - Discarded by Firefox if the element is not SVG.
- other obscure properties

  - not semantic, feels arbitrary.

### Testing details

(I think this won't work on this website, but posting it anyway)

```js
(function ($) {
  var names = [];
  var rules = document.styleSheets[1].rules;
  for (var iRule = 0; iRule < rules.length; ++iRule) {
    console.log(rules[iRule]);
    var styles = rules[iRule].style;
    for (var iStyle = 0; iStyle < styles.length; ++iStyle) {
      names.push(styles[iStyle]);
    }
  }
  names.push('varname');
  names.push('--varname');
  names.push('cx');
  names.push('unknownprop');
  names.push('transition');
  names.push('transition-duration');
  var values = {};
  var $div = $('div');
  var div = $div[0];
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(div);
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    var name = names[i];
    try {
     var valueJQ = $div.css(name);
    }
    catch (e) {
      valueJQ = e;
    }
    var valueGCSOffset = style[name];
    var valueGCSgPV = style.getPropertyValue(name);
   values[name] = [valueJQ, valueGCSOffset, valueGCSgPV];
  }
  
  values['div::before {content}'] = window.getComputedStyle(div, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
  
  $('div').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(values, null, 2) + '</pre>');
  console.log(names, values);
})(jQuery || null);
```

```css
div {
  content: 'xyz';
  --varname: 'abc';
  cx: 0;
  unknwownprop: 'uuu';
  transition: max-height 3s;
}

div::before {
  display: none;
  content: 'content before';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

IE11:

```
{
  "content": [
    "normal",
    "normal",
    "normal"
  ],
  "transition-property": [
    "max-height",
    "max-height",
    "max-height"
  ],
  "transition-duration": [
    "3s",
    "3s",
    "3s"
  ],
  "transition-timing-function": [
    "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)",
    "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)",
    "cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1)"
  ],
  "transition-delay": [
    "0s",
    "0s",
    "0s"
  ],
  "display": [
    "block",
    "block",
    "block"
  ],
  "varname": [
    null,
    null,
    ""
  ],
  "--varname": [
    null,
    null,
    ""
  ],
  "cx": [
    "0",
    "0",
    ""
  ],
  "unknownprop": [
    null,
    null,
    ""
  ],
  "transition": [
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "div::before {content}": "\"content before\""
}
```